# Information about Intel(R) Xeon(R) Platinum 8151 CPU @ 3.40GHz used in some AWS EC2 instances?

Tags: amazon-ec2, intel

I started zd1.metal AWS instance and got this output from lscpu commmand:

```
...
Model name:          Intel(R) Xeon(R) Platinum 8151 CPU @ 3.40GHz
...
```

but when I google this processor I can not find any official info about it, ie. there is no this processor on https://ark.intel.com . Anyone knows why or where can I find this info?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Custom cloud SKU, possibly AWS only. Edit: Not even on wikichip.org, which leaked some other AWS models. Not on ARK certainly implies custom.

Platinum 8100 series indicates a high end Skylake SP. Introduced circa 2017. Usually this is enough for capacity planning, but if you require specific details please edit your question.

z1d.metal advertises 24 cores, so you get one CPU.

Comment: Actually I can't find realistic looking 8151 specs leaked anywhere, was a different model I found on wikichip.  AWS doesn't think the specifics are important, as they are not giving details.

Answer (score 1):

I first heard of this during an AWS Admin training seminar a couple years ago. Our trainer was talking about how AWS gets custom Xeon CPU's from Intel. He couldn't get into the specifics about it though unfortunately.

Doing a check with Google though, I was able to find a reference to this specific instance type from AWS itself, and that is uses a custom CPU. https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/z1d/

I imagine AWS doesn't publicly disclose the exact specs of this CPU, but there are benchmarks to be found on it.